# Rails 4 installing SSL certificarte

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ssl

I just recently bought an SSL certificate from Symantec. The give me 2 different types of certificate `IntermediateCA.cer` and `ssl_certificate.cer`. Both the files begins and end with `----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `----END CERTIFICATE----`. How can I install them on my AWS server?

My rails app currently running on AWS. Thanks!!

Comment: Here's a guide that explains the processes: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9593/0/installing-a-ssl-certificate-on-amazon-web-services-aws

Comment: @Oleander is both `crt` and `cer` same?

Comment: @d3bug3r They are not the same. One is your certificate and one is your chain file. In any case both are needed.

Comment: @datasage. So do I just copy and paste into AWS load balancers?

Comment: @d3bug3r, Yes you would use both of them in your ELB setup. There should be fields for both.